# cast of template classes of inheritable classes

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have `Base` and `Derived` classes and template class `Container` which argument can be `Base` as well as `Derived`. And I need to cast `Container<Derived>` to `Container<Base>` is it possible to do that? Which cast I should use?

Comment: What is your Container and what are you trying to do?

Comment: An alternative is to make a class that wraps either Container<Derived> or Container<Base> and has functions to read Base* objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. `Container<Derived>` does not derive from `Container<Base>`, they are just two instances of the same class template.

This makes sense: imagine a `Container<Derived>` would be a valid substitute for a `Container<Base>` for a function that expects a `Container<Base>`, and imagine to have a second class `Derived2` which derives from `Base`, but which is unrelated to `Derived`:

```
void foo(Container<Base>& cont)
{
    Derived2 obj;
    cont.push_back(obj);
}

Container<Derived> c;
foo(c);
```

In the above code snippet, you would be trying to insert an object of type `Derived2` into a container of `Derived` elements. Definitely not a good thing.

Moreover, if you want to take advantage of polymorphic behavior, you should use (smart) pointers in your containers:

```
Container<std::shared_ptr<Base>> cb;
// ... fill it in...

Container<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> cd;
for (auto &pB : cb)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Derived> pD = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(pB);
    if (pD != nullptr)
    {
        cd.push_back(pD);
    }
}
```

Here is a (possible) complete example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Container = std::vector<T>;

struct Base { virtual ~Base() { } };
struct Derived : Base { };

int main()
{
    Container<std::shared_ptr<Base>> cb;
    cb.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived>());
    cb.push_back(std::make_shared<Base>());
    cb.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived>());

    Container<std::shared_ptr<Derived>> cd;
    for (auto &pB : cb)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Derived> pD = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(pB);
        if (pD != nullptr)
        {
            cd.push_back(pD);
        }
    }

    std::cout << cd.size(); // Prints 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. You will have to create a new container and do the casting on a element-by-element basis.

Still note you may do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {
};

class B: public A{

};
int main() {
    vector<B> b(5);
    vector<A> a(b.begin(), b.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour well of course it is. The OP wants to convert `Container<B>` to `Container<A>` that requires slicing

Answer (score 0):

Note that to operate polymorphically, you need to use pointers or references. Your container may do that, but maybe not -- you haven't told us.

If you had `Container<Base*>`, you could hold both base and derived objects in it (though you may want to consider making that `Container< std::unique_ptr<Base> >` or similar).

If you had a `Container<Derived>` (or `Container<Derived*>`), you could make a parallel `Container<Base*>` that pointed to those elements, but beware them getting out of sync.

The other option is just to cast the elements one-by-one as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

If everthing is derived of a non-template abstract interface class, which holds all the needed methods, the vTable will do the cast automagically :-D. You will then need containers of pointers of this interface class. I did just that with a composite pattern, works like a charme!

Comment: you can't use dynamic or static casts because there's no relation between the instantiations  of the template class

Comment: hmm i though so, but i wasnt sure, because of the templates. But if he derives the container of a interface class, there would be a relation? I'll better delete that bit of my answer.